# C# application generating "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel"

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, tls1.2, dotnet-httpclient

I have a C# application targeting the `.NET Framework 4.7.2` that tries to send an `HTTP POST` to a remote server. I get the following exception: "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.". Attempting the exact same HTTP POST on the exact same server in Postman works just fine, so I must be missing something in my application. Right before the message is sent using the `HttpClient` instance I have created, I set the Security Protocol to `Tls12`:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

What else do I need to set in my application to ensure that the remote server does not close my connection?

Edit: This is the code snippet used to send the request and receive the response. For privacy reasons, I have hidden the name of the class that contains the response.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
  try
  {
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

     response = client.SendAsync(message, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).Result;
     var paymentResponse = response.GetData<PaymentResponseDto>();
     var responseAsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paymentResponse);
     // do something with the response
```

Edit: We have created an identical test environment in our client's network - got the same error. In the exception stack, I see this:

```
Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

Any ideas? Is this something to do with the Tls 1.2 protocol, as Mate suggests? Again, the server is Windows Server 2012 R2. I asked the client to look into the possibility to update it to Server 2016.

Comment: Which windows version are you using on that server?

Comment: On previous versions of windows server 2016, it doesn't work. You need to move to >= 2016.

Comment: @Mate Hi, the version of the OS is Windows Server 2012R2 Standard. Can you point me to a resource online that specify this limitation? I would need to arm myself with some serious documentation before I can get the IT of our client to upgrade these servers. Also, wouldn't Postman face the same limitation?

Comment: I try to find one, but we spent several days with the same scenario.  Maybe you colud try once with windows sever 2016 without any change on your code.  ;)  . Postman doesn't  use .net fwk.

Comment: Moreover, your client maybe have another instance with windows server 2016, to avoid an upgrade. Win server 2012 will die in a couple of months.

Comment: Please don't post code in image format.  Post code in text format and mark it down as code.  [Here's why](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).  You can edit the text to anonymize the name of the class to `ExampleResponse` as necessary.

Comment: Thanks Wyck - I have made the change.

Comment: What's the *full* exception text? Is there an inner exception? Try removing the code that sets `SecurityProtocol`. .NET 4.7.2 will use the best available algorithm and Windows Server 2012R2 is supposed to support TLS1.2 out of the box. It's likely the problem was caused by incorrect patching. It's also possible that the server uses an algorithm not supported by Windows 2012R2.

Comment: @Mate - this link seems to suggest that TLS 1.2 is available on Windows Server 2012 R2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client

Comment: TLS1.2 is the umbrella specification that can cover multiple more specific algorithms and key lengths (cipher suites). In [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73569562/tls-1-2-handshake-fails-on-windows-server-2012-r2?rq=1) for example, algorithm restrictions caused Kestrel to fail. POSTMAN doesn't necessarily use the OS libraries

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That exception message I posted ("The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel") was the Inner/Inner Exception. The Exception message is "One or more errors occurred". The Inner Exception message is "An error occurred while sending the request"

Comment: If the client and server can't agree on a cipher suite an inner exception may say so. It could also be that the server is using a self-signed certificate, which isn't trusted by default. If you really trust that server you could add the certificate to the trusted certificates. You can verify if that's the issue by instructing POSTMAN to verify the certificate too. Or you can navigate to that URL in your browser. If the cert isn't trusted, the lock next to the address bar will show a warning

Comment: If you really trust the server you can add the certificate by right clicking on the padlock, inspecting the certificate and adding it to the trusted certificates. Although it's better to get the server to use a proper certificate. Lets Encrypt certificates are free. For internal sites, you can install a certificate authority on the network. Eg Active Directory has Certificate Services that are trusted by the entire domain and can issue certificates for servers

Comment: We read that link. It doesn't work. Do you think your client prefers to try that on a production server or use a new version of windows server?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I've added an edit with more details. Any ideas?

Comment: While debugging certificate compatibility issues on an old Windows server, I noticed that Internet Explorer's behaviour best matched the problematic .NET Full framework code with issues. When we got IE to open a TLS connection to the server, then the .NET code would too. Other browers and tools would work all the time. I think in the end some cipher suites needed to be (re)enabled (registry change + server reboot), but I don't have those details documented regrettably.